# Android- twitter.getFriendsStatuses missing in twitter4j 2.2.6

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j

I am currently migrating from twitter4j-core-2.1.11.jar to 2.2.6.

```
twitter.getFriendsStatuses(twitter.getScreenName()).toString();
```

I don't see any such methods in 2.2.6. Surprisingly the libraries are not backward compatible.

Is there an equivalent method in 2.2.6 or some other way to fetch Friends statuses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to get this method in twitter4j-core-2.2.6.jar

```
twitter.getFriendsStatuses(twitter.getScreenName()).toString();
```

so had to stick with 2.1.11

If anyone has a better option, please reply here, it might help someone else who comes searching.